# sql loop with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Im trying to generate a bunch of discounts codes. These have foreign key contraints.

At the moment I have

```
INSERT INTO code (title, code, desc) VALUES ('code1','XPISY9','test code');
INSERT INTO code_details (code_id, used, attempts) VALUES (
 SELECT code_id from code where code = 'XPISY9',0,0);
```

The code_id in code_details is a foreign key for code_id in the code table.

What would be the best way to create a loop where I can generate a set of these values (around 100). I would need the code to be a not repeating random value.

Any help would be appreciated.

THanks

Comment: Being SQL a declarative language, and not an imperative one, trying to make a loop which generates something in SQL is not a good approach. Instead, you should look for trying to express all the codes you want by selecting them from somewhere by accomplishing some condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I decided to put together a procedure for this and it worked great:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE vouchergen(IN length INT(10) ,IN duration VARCHAR(20),IN sponsor VARCHAR(20),IN amount INT(10))
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;

WHILE (i< amount) DO

SET @vcode= CONCAT(BINARY brand , UPPER(SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 6)));

INSERT INTO code (title, code, desc) VALUES (CONCAT(brand,i),@vcode,CONCAT(length,' ',duration));

INSERT INTO code_details (code_id, used, attempts) VALUES (
 SELECT code_id from code where code = @vcode,0,0);

SET i=i+1;

END WHILE;
END$$;
```

I can then call this to gen however many i want:

```
CALL vouchergen(1,'week',APPL,400);
CALL vouchergen(1,'month',APPL,100);
CALL vouchergen(1,'day',APPL,200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your 100 or so records in the code table, you can add the code details in one statement:

```
INSERT INTO code_details (code_id, used, attempts) 
SELECT code, 0, 0
FROM code;
```

Generating the code records in the first place is another matter and is probably best done by using some other tool to generate 100 insert statements in a text file which you can then execute.

I've seen that done with every scripting language possible - chose your favourite. I've even seen Excel used with a column for the id and string formula to generate the insert statements.